# SQL Server schema permissions for stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is what I am trying to accomplish with SQL Server, is this possible, and if so, what is the best approach?

1. Move all tables from the `dbo` schema, or change permissions to view only for anything but a stored procedure
2. Only stored procedures will have access to write and update the tables within the schema, `dbo` or a private schema.

I am doing this because I am the only dev in my company who has any type of database management experience; the other devs just edit tables live, create and update willy-nilly. I am coming in as a senior and am trying to prevent direct table create/update/delete; I believe all creates and updates should be managed through a stored procedure to help maintain data integrity and ensure proper time stamps are updated.

Is doing something like this possible? If so, what is the best approach?

Comment: Sounds like the users should just have explicit permission to execute on the database and nothing else. Then, provided everything has the **same owner** then the permissions will be implicitly granted when the SP is executed.

Comment: Thanks, that should work.

Comment: How many devs are there in your company? Perhaps it would be better (surly for the long run) to give them a crush course in SQL instead. Create / alter tables is one thing, insert / update data is another. Seems like you are mixing the two in your question....